# html not proberly scaled for ios device

Tags: html, ios, css, objective-c

I'm trying to embed a html page into a webView in my ios app. however whatever i do i can't seem to make it scale properly. As you can see on the current app the text and image exceed the width of the screen, which is not the wanted result. How come it does not scale properly, when i've set all widths to 100% and set scaleToFitPage to true?

[image]

viewDidLoad

```
    webView.scrollView.delegate = self
    webView.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    webView.scalesPageToFit = true
```

HTML code

```
<!-- template.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            font-family: 'PT Sans';
            margin-left:0;
            margin-right:0;
            margin-top: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .text_div{
            padding-left:10px;
            padding-right:100px;
            font-size:26px;
            width: 100%;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing:
            border-box; box-sizing: border-box;

        }

    .text_div p {
         display: block;
         width: 100%;
         word-wrap: break-word;
         -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         -webkit-box-sizing:
         border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .title{
        font-size: 40px;
        padding-left:5px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        padding-right: 10px;
          margin-top: 10px;
          width: 100%;
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          -webkit-box-sizing:
          border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .main_image {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center; 
    }
    .main_image img{
        width: auto;
        height: auto;

    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

   <div class="main_image" style="background-image:url([[[main_image]]])" title="[[[alt_desc]]]"></div>
   <p class="title">[[[title]]]</p>
   <div class="text_div">
        <p>[[[full_text]]]</p>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.4; ">` in the header.

Comment: didnt do anything but making the text and image bigger

Comment: Check this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html if it helps.

Comment: can u put the whole HTML with your css code  in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and paste the link here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2b9m40f3/

works fine here

Comment: ok..let me have a look

Comment: in which device and  ios version you are trying?are you using auto layout contraints or auto resize? it is working fine in iPhone 5s with iOS 8.3 with auto layout @KæmpeKlunker

Comment: Here is the [screenshot](http://imgur.com/KQ6fldw) how it looks.

Comment: i'm showing on the simulator ios6. i'm found the solution. i was missing some constraints

Comment: Don't use `scalesPageToFit ` as you have got all in css, it should work directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.View.frame];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:html_file_url];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];

webView.scalesPageToFit=YES;

webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale=10.0;

webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale=1.0;

webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

[self.view addSubview:webView];

[webView loadRequest:request];